# Getting $mdDialog.alert error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, angular-material

I'm trying to activate an Alert Dialog with Angular Material Design.

In my controller, I have:

```
angular.module('KidHubApp')
  .controller('ActivityCtrl', ['$scope','$meteor', '$stateParams', '$mdDialog', '$state', function($scope, $meteor, $stateParams, $state, $mdDialog){
```

...

```
$mdDialog.show(
$mdDialog.alert()
.clickOutsideToClose(true)
.title('No timeslot selected.')
.textContent('Please select a date and a timeslot to make a reservation.')
.ok("Got it!")
.targetEvent(ev)
      );
}
```

However, I'm getting in console :

> TypeError: $mdDialog.alert is not a function

How can I solve this ?

Comment: You can try to add the $mdDialog object to the global window object and then test it in the developer console..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function params don't match injection order...

```
angular.module('KidHubApp')
  .controller('ActivityCtrl', ['$scope','$meteor', '$stateParams', '$mdDialog', '$state', function($scope, $meteor, $stateParams, $state, $mdDialog){
```

should be

```
angular.module('KidHubApp')
  .controller('ActivityCtrl', ['$scope','$meteor', '$stateParams', '$mdDialog', '$state', function($scope, $meteor, $stateParams, $mdDialog, $state){
```

swapping `$state` and `$mdDialog` in your function params, to match the order theyre injected in...

Comment: Stupid me... Thanks!